# what is Extensions in asp.net mvc2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

can u pls tell me what is the use of Extension( folder)/ how to use it in asp.net mvc2 framework...(extension is under the project name, like controllers, models, views...)

i mean the \Extension directory....

Answer (score 1):

It's an arbitrary folder, just like `/Joe/`.

It probably contains extension methods.

Answer (score 1):

The extension folder is nothing that comes with a new ASP.NET MVC 2 project. We can only guess what that folder might contain without seeing the actual source code.